# How to build a sdk include c lib

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I got a c .lib and I need to build a sdk to include it.
I put it in libs, I have try to make a sdk use kotlin but i can't access method from that lib.
How could I build a sdk to include it and make iteration in app?

Comment: What do you mean by ".lib"? How did you build the library, or where does it come from? What you should have is an .so file, built with the Android NDK.

Comment: I don't have a .so file, my teammate build his c project output one .lib file and  .dll file to me. is it only way to use .so?

Comment: Sounds like your teammate is building the library for Windows. They need to build it for Android using the Android NDK.